# Ruby, properly error handling class constructor options

Tags: ruby

I am working on an application in Ruby, and I am trying to write a clean and efficient API and would need properly error handle options passed to a class constructor.

For instance:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(options = {})
    @some_opt = options[:some_opt]
    @some_other_opt = options[:some_other_opt]
  end
end

sc = SomeClass.new(:some_opt => 'foo', :some_other_opt => 'bar')
```

How would I make sure, that if the user adds an option wich the application does not accept, the application will raise an error?

```
sc = SomeClass.new(:some_opt => 'foo', :some_new_opt => 'foobar')  # => Unknown option 'some_new_opt'
```

Would it be better to only use the options that you need to, and disregard any other options passed to the class?

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby versions 1.8 and 1.9 disregarding the extra options is generally how that situation is handled. You can raise an error if you want, but **I wouldn't recommend it**:

```
require "set"

class SomeClass
  ACCEPTED_KEYWORDS = Set[:some_opt, :some_other_opt]

  def initialize(options = {})
    raise ArgumentError unless options.keys.all? {|k| ACCEPTED_KEYWORDS.include? k }

    # Rest of the code...
  end
end
```

For Ruby version 2.0 and above you can use [keyword arguments](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), and you can make them required from version 2.1 onwards.